# Possible meanings of 校 - exam?

Tags: kanji

[Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%A0%A1%20%23kanji) gives "exam" as one of the possible meanings of 校, but I was not able to find any words with this kanji which has a meaning related to "exam". Is there any?

My interest in this comes from the fact that I have started using Helsig's method to memorize kanji, but it seems counterproductive to me that some keywords are not related to any meaning of the corresponding kanji. Therefore, I have decided to replace each of such keywords with one of the corresponding kanji meanings. There is a keyword "exam" for this kanji and I'm considering updating it to something which makes more sense, such as "school".

obs: I have looked in the list of words which use this Kanji in Jisho. If there is a better way to find words which use a kanji, I'd be glad to know

Comment: All i could find (except the exam definition) is that Wiktionary doesnt define it as exam but as school building, if that makes you feel any better :d https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%A0%A1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

校 does not mean "exam" in the sense of students' written test, but it means "examination" or "investigation" in the following compounds:

- 校正 proofreading
- 校了 proofreading completed
- 校閲 copyedit / reviewing / proofreading
- <sup>☆</sup>校合 collation (comparison of different versions of the same classical work)
- 校本 a survey book on different versions of the same classical work
- <sup>☆</sup>勘校 to examine and correct

<sup>(☆: rare words, you probably won't ever need them)</sup>

As you can see, "exam" is too broad, and it may be better to think of this as "careful reading". Jisho.org sometimes has errors, so I recommend checking monolingual dictionaries whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As "exam" can only mean "a test of a student's knowledge or skill in a particular subject" in English (ref: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/exam), that meaning of the kanji is obviously wrong then. I'll replace Heisig's keyword with one of the kanji true meanings. Regarding monolingual dictionaries, I prefer them too, but I'm still a beginner in Japanese and they are too advanced for me right now.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista exam just mean a test!  you goto the doctors for an eye exam or even just an exam (in the sense of a check up). exam has quite a broad usage and meanings in english.

Comment: @A.Ellett Indeed "exam" may also mean "a formal test that you must pass in order to earn a particular qualification or be allowed to do a particular job" or "an inspection by a medical professional to establish the extent and nature of any sickness or injury". I don't think there is any other meaning of "exam" and the Cambridge dictionary entry I referenced above agrees. Anyway, the relevant point here is that the kanji discussed above (校) does not have any of those meanings in any Japanese word.

Comment: 校本 usually corresponds to "critical edition". 校合 and 勘校 would be a basic word if you're a philology student :)